# S3 registerStreamWrapper and fseek

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using PHP SDK for AWS and S3. This is part of my code:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
's3' => array(
    'seekable' => true
)));
$stream = fopen("s3://{$bucketname}/{$key}", 'r',false,$context);
$length = $byte_to - $byte_from + 1 ;
$speed = 1000*1024 ;//1000KB
file_put_contents("test.txt"," before \n",FILE_APPEND);
        $im = fseek($stream,$byte_from);
        file_put_contents("test.txt"," im=".$im." \n",FILE_APPEND);           
  while($length>0) { 
  if($length > $speed)
        $read = $speed ;
  else
        $read = $length;

    $length = $length - $read;

    echo fread($stream,$read);
}
```

After checking test.txt I saw "before" was saved to test.txt (only).It seems that fseek doesn't work. How can I change this code to a better code?

Comment: In this code example `$byte_from` is not defined. Is this example incomplete?

Comment: Also in this code part variable `$length` defined after condition, so condition `$length>0` will be false everytime.

Comment: This is part of my code.

Comment: If this example is incomplete please edit question to provide [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added two lines.

Comment: $byte_to and $byte_from is defined by HTTP_RANGE. I know that fseek doesn't work and maybe hangs.

Comment: Why do you think you know it? Before blaming fseek(or another library code) you should check yours(and provide this info for us).

Comment: I used this code:    file_put_contents("test.txt"," before \n",FILE_APPEND);
            fread($stream, 1024);            
            $im = fseek($stream,$byte_from);
            file_put_contents("test.txt"," im=".$im." \n",FILE_APPEND);

Comment: and only "before" was saved to test.txt

Comment: please edit question with this info.

Comment: OK.I added file_put_contents to code.